# Python/Pygame How to make something disappear off of screen after a set amount of time?

Tags: python, timer, pygame, startup

I was wondering if there was any sort of code to make something disappear from the screen after a set time? Something like an intro to your game?

Comment: You should be tracking time as it passes anyways, instead of relying on frames to pace your game. Define some variables (OOP optional) to track time passing since certain conditions (i.e. 5s after a keypress, 10s after begin etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the [timer](/questions/tagged/timer) tag so use a `threading.Timer` object to call a function after some time:

```
class Menu:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active = True

        # start a timer for the menu
        Timer(3, self.reset).start()

    def update(self, scr):
        if self.active:
            surf = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
            surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
            scr.blit(surf, (270, 190))

    def reset(self):
        self.active = False

menu = Menu()

while True:
    pygame.display.update()
    queue = pygame.event.get()
    scr.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in queue:
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()

    menu.update(scr)
```

Comment: So what would be the easiest way to put this into a class? I have a start menu pre-built that I'm trying to activate using this with classes.

Comment: @JustinFarr There you go!

Comment: Thank you! It's telling me 'Timer' is not defined. How exactly do I define it? sorry for asking so many questions..

Comment: Remember you have to import it: `from threading import Timer`

Comment: Please be sure to mark as answer with the check on the side. Let me know if this doesn't make sense or if you need anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`pygame.time.Clock`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) to track time as it passes.

Comment: `pygame.time.Clock` has been introduced so that your application code can continue running in the main event loop. Introducing threads can lead to unwanted side effects if used improperly.

Comment: There is no unwanted side effect because it is a separate thread than from the main thread. See the program below.